# Reasoning of the Domain Model for the task assignement example not clear

Tags: optaplanner

I am currently an intern at a company which plans to do a slightly different version of the task assignment problem with Optaplanner. So I thought, it would be beneficial to study the example from Optaplanner.

But regarding the following questions, my instructor and my "co-intern" couldn't help me:

Questions:
If We look at the DOMAIN-MODEL from the Optaplanner API:[DOMAIN-MODEL for the task assignment problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckjra.png)

i) What does the class taskOrEmployee represent? I am confused because both employee and task inherit the attributes of taskOrEmployee.

ii) If we look at the code, it says that taskOrEmployee is a Planning Entity (not shown in domain model), but employee is a Problem Fact. Why can a Problem Fact inherit from a Planning Entity?

Summed up: I clearly don't know what taskOrEmployee is.

kind regards

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TaskOrEmployee is an interface implemented by both Task and Employee.

It's a result of using aa chained planning variable. For a future OptaPlanner version we'll support something like

```
@PlanningEntity class Employee {

     @PlanningVariableCollection // Not yet supported.
     List<Task> taskList;
}
```

Anyway, now you 'll have to make due with a chained planning variable (see docs).

TaskOrEmployee has a shadow variable (the next task), so it needs a @PlanningEntity annotation. Task has a genuine planning variable (the previous task) (and maybe a shadow variable too), so that too needs a @PlanningEntity annotation.

Comment: Hello Geoffrey, thank you for your answer!
Okay I understand now, that we want to model a list of planning variables. How ever there is still one question: Why is taskOrEmployee an abstract class and not an interface? - In VehicleRouting and TSP the equivalent to taskOrEmployee is the interface StandStill. Or am I thinking too much and it all comes down to the preferences of the coder?